# SAML 2.0 to OpenID Connect missing SUB claim

Tags: openid-connect, saml-2.0, adfs, foxids

I have connected an AD FS as SAML 2.0 up-party on FoxIDs and my application is connected with OpenID Connect as down-party.

I'm not receiving a SUB claim in my application, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FoxIDs convert between SAML 2.0 and JWT claims. Where the `sub` claim is converted from the SAML 2.0 `NameID` attribute/claim. The `NameID` claim has the claim type `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`.

Either you need to update the AD FS configuration to also issue the `NameID` claim. Which results in a `sub` claim with the `NameID` claim value.

Alternatively, if the AD FS e.g. are issuing a `UPN` (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn`) claim you can define a claims transformation in FoxIDs mapping the `UPN` (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn`) claim to a `NameID` (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`) claim. This results in a `sub` claim with the `UPN` claim value.

To debug you can temporary add a `NameID` (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`) claim with a constant value, which results in a sub claim.